# parentheses in c macro function

Tags: c, gcc, macros, parentheses

I have this macro definition:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUG
#endif
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUG_SNAP(format) snap format
#else
#define DEBUG_SNAP(format)
#endif
```

and it is invoked like

```
DEBUG_SNAP( ( "Value1", "Value2", "Value3" ) )
```

This is in code I have the analyze and I am not allowed to change.

The problem is that the gcc c compiler complains: It is defined with one parameter, but it is invoked with three parameters. I can understand that the intention is to use one parameter, in this case seen as the whole expression `( "Value1", "Value2", "Value3" )`.

I am **not** allowed to change the code, but I am allowed to play with C precompiler options.

Question: Is there some option in the gcc C precompiler to make it understand that an expression like ( P1, P2, P3 ) is in fact a single paramter value, rather than three parameters?

---

Here is sample code. 
I have a header file called debug.h with this content

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUG
#endif
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUG_SNAP(format) snap format
#else
#define DEBUG_SNAP(format)
#endif
```

I have this C file calldebug.c with this content

```
#include "debug.h"

extern snap (char *parm1, char *parm2, char *parm3);
void func
{
    DEBUG_SNAP("parm1", "parm2", "parm3");
}
```

The gcc precompiler returns the error

error: macro "DEBUG_SNAP" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 1

More information:

1. This was originally C code in an Unisys 2200 environment where the UC compiler was used.
2. This is an analysis project running in Windows. Changing the code goes contrary to the intention of analysis, i.e. to analyze EXISTING code rather than modified code.
3. My hope is to be able to keep the code as is, and only employ gcc precompile options to resolve the problem.

Comment: Are both the snippets you show defined in side the same file? And you are not allowed to changed neither the one nor the other?

Comment: Please produce a **proper** [mcve], including the actual error message. If I paste these 2 to a C file they preprocess without problems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please. My test code based on your description compiles fine: https://godbolt.org/g/TfcVdX

Comment: [Seems to work OK](http://ideone.com/AfoD0u) - please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This `DEBUG_SNAP( ( "Value1", "Value2", "Value3" ) )` passes **one** parameter, namely `( "Value1", "Value2", "Value3" )`. 3 parameters are passed if doing `DEBUG_SNAP( "Value1", "Value2", "Value3" )`.

Comment: You are right. This is my dilemma. This code compiles fine with the Unisys C compiler. Should I redefine the macro in the gcc command line? Maybe using -D option?

Answer (score 1):

Your example code is failing to use the second pair of parentheses. It needs to be:

```
DEBUG_SNAP(("parm1", "parm2", "parm3"));
```

**not**

```
DEBUG_SNAP("parm1", "parm2", "parm3");
```

That's the cause of the problem.

Apart from that:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUG
#endif
```

does nothing. You can delete that. And you should specify a return type in the `extern snap (char *parm1, char *parm2, char *parm3);` (the `extern` keyword there is effectively a comment—you can delete it too).

If you absolutely cannot touch the code, you can use command line options to override the `debug.h` header with variadic macro `DEBUG_SNAP(...) snap(__VA_ARGS__)` or with `DEBUG_SNAP(A,B,C) snap(A,B,C)`. Then you won't need the 2nd pair of parentheses.